# Distribution of the OLS estimator in a predictive regression model

Tags: time-series, least-squares

I have a model of the following kind:

$y_t = \alpha +\beta x_{t-1} + u_t$

$x_t = \rho x_{t-1} + v_t$

Where:

- $Cov(u_t, v_t) = \sigma_{uv}\neq 0$
- $u_t \sim N(0, \sigma^2_u)$
- $v_t \sim N(0, \sigma^2_v)$
- Both ${u_t}$ and ${v_t}$ independent across $t$.

I am trying to compute the OLS estimator $\hat\beta^{OLS}$, and its variance. I tried to follow the calculations in [Stambaugh(1999)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304405X99000410) but I can't follow his calculations, as he seems to be multiplying a $T\times 1$ vector by a $2T \times 2T$ matrix.

Additionally, I need to calculate the estimator $\hat\delta_k^{OLS}$ and its variance:

$y_t = \phi + \delta_k x_{t-k} + \epsilon_t$, where the data generating process of $y_t$ and $x_t$ is the one above.

Comment: Please state a clear question that the community can answer. What is it you do not understand ?